# Calculate EndDate using a formula on Excel

Tags: excel, algorithm, formula

So i'm trying to write a formula that gives me an endDateTime to a project knowing just two things:

> 1. startDate;
> 2. How many hours it will take to finish the project;

The problem here it is that i cannot use vba just the ordinary excel formulas.

I tried to use =WORKDAY.INTL(date,days,"workingDaysPattern",holidaysTable) but my problem is that one of the premises is that workingTimePerDay is a variable too.

> Example:
>
> startDateTime => 29 November 2016 at 10:00 and it will take 125 hours to complete.
>
> Every Monday i have 2 hours to work;
>
> Tuesday 3 hours;
>
> Wednesday 8 hours;
>
> Thursday 10 hours;
>
> Friday 5 hours;
>
> Saturday 12 hours;
>
> Sunday 0 hours;
>
> Giving a total of 40 hours.
>   Ok, i could calculate average and say that it will take 3 weeks and 0,125 of a week. Then i just have to sum it up until i make the expected result, but... since i don't have a "while" or any kind of cycle i don't know how to get there.
>   Also because i have to respect the holidays so i cannot just build an array formula like:
>
> {=SUM(CHOOSE(WEEKDAY(ROW(INDIRECT(date1&":"&date2))),1,2,3,4,5,6,7))}

Any thoughts?

Comment: What about a UDF? It's a formula that you create with vba code.

Comment: I wish @Andreas, it would be much easier to accomplish.

Comment: So why not use UDF? I don't get it.... Does your answer mean that you are done with the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. i got it. Just in case if someone needs this. (i doubt it)
the things we know:

- **StartDate**; **TaskWorkingHoursNeeded**; **WorkingHoursPerDay**; **HolidaysTable**

First we create a table with working days respecting [WEEKDAY function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/WEEKDAY-function-60e44483-2ed1-439f-8bd0-e404c190949a) . Because we know the total working hours per week (summing **WorkingHoursPerDay**), calculate the total working weeks (exceeded):

```
ExceededWorkingWeeks = CEILING(TaskWorkingHoursNeeded/WorkingHoursPerWeek;0)
```

Second, if it was just like that, in how many days (exceeded):

```
ExceededWorkingDays = exceededWorkingWeeks / countDaysWhereExistWorkingHours
```

Third, in how many hours (exceeded):

```
ExceededWorkingHours = ExceededWorkingWeeks * WorkingHoursPerWeek
```

So, now we can calculate the exceeded end date if we were using **ExceededWorkingDays** not forgetting the holidays and the days of a week that we work ([Resource](https://exceljet.net/formula/add-days-exclude-certain-days-of-week)):

```
ExceededEndDate = WORKDAY.INTL(StartDate, ExceededWorkingDays, "patternWorkingWeekDays", HolidaysTable)
```

Now the "ugly" part. A lot of if's and else's and we are done.

For 7 **value** positions starting 0 till 6 first we calculate the day subtracting **value** day to **ExceededEndDate**. Then to know if this day matters we calculate if this is a working day on our **patternWorkingWeekDays** and it is not a holiday:

`CheckWorkDay = NETWORKDAYS.INTL(ValueNewDate;ValueNewDate;"patternWorkingWeekDays";HolidaysTable)`

If returns 1 it means that the hours of this working day are to subtract to **ExceededWorkingHours**. Calculate weekday using a "index alignment":

`ValueNewWeekDay = 7-MOD(ABS(value+(7-WEEKDAY(ExceededEndDate)));7)`

Using this **ValueNewWeekDay** for indexing to the table with my working days i could know how many hours i have to subtract to **CurrentExceededWorkingHours**.

For each working day, not holiday, subtract working hours to **CurrentExceededWorkingHours** until we get `CurrentExceededWorkingHours < TaskWorkingHoursNeeded`. Of course checking for each **value** if **ValueNewDate** is lower than **StartDate**.

Like the client wanted we can put all this formulas in just one cell.

> RESUME:
>
> Real end date is calculated by subtracting for a week (7 days) the exceeded hours.